# Spark Streaming Error for JavaNetworkWordCount Program (netcat)

Tags: java, apache-spark, streaming, netcat, word-count

While running the spark streaming program (JavaNetworkWordCount.java) program, I get no error when I type nothing on the netcat server. However, as soon as I type a statement like "Hello World" and press enter the terminal shows an error (see below). I am using ubuntu in virtual box (host: windows) with 2 GB RAM. The batch interval is set to 10 seconds.

```
spark-submit --class JavaNetworkWordCount --master 'local[4]' target/streaming-project-1.0.jar
```

(I have used mvn package to make the .jar file using JavaNetworkWordCount.java file)

For netcat which is running in a different terminal, the command is:

```
nc -lk 9999
```

### Time: 1475884960000 ms

```
16/10/07 17:02:50 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 5.0 (TID 3)
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: JavaNetworkWordCount$1.call(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Iterable;
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaDStreamLike$$anonfun$fn$1$1.apply(JavaDStreamLike.scala:172)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaDStreamLike$$anonfun$fn$1$1.apply(JavaDStreamLike.scala:172)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:371)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:327)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalSorter.insertAll(ExternalSorter.scala:202)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.SortShuffleWriter.write(SortShuffleWriter.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:203)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
16/10/07 17:02:50 ERROR SparkUncaughtExceptionHandler: Uncaught exception in thread Thread[Executor task launch worker-1,5,main]
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: JavaNetworkWordCount$1.call(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Iterable;
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaDStreamLike$$anonfun$fn$1$1.apply(JavaDStreamLike.scala:172)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaDStreamLike$$anonfun$fn$1$1.apply(JavaDStreamLike.scala:172)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:371)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:327)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalSorter.insertAll(ExternalSorter.scala:202)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.SortShuffleWriter.write(SortShuffleWriter.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:203)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
16/10/07 17:02:50 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 5.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
```

Comment: Please show the commands you're running to start this program and netcat.

Comment: spark-submit --class JavaNetworkWordCount --master 'local[4]' target/streaming-project-1.0.jar

(I have used mvn package to make the .jar file using JavaNetworkWordCount.java file)

For netcat which is running in a different terminal, the command is: nc -lk 9999

Comment: The program is similar to this: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#a-quick-example

Comment: It seems like you've got a pretty vague problem here; it's not really possible to answer it, especially without the code that's causing the issue. Stack Overflow is good at answering specific questions. I would suggest that you start by trying the exact example they provided. Once you get that working, you can modify it a little at a time and test it after each change. If you make a change, it doesn't work, and you can't figure out why, come back here and show us the change (not the whole program) and the error message and you'll get a lot more attention to your post.

Comment: I just ran your exact example with the exact setup. no issues. what version of spark are you using? and did you build spark yourself? or download a prebuilt version?